# sql select only first 3 rows from second table

Tags: sql, oracle

I only need 3 records from child table.

```
CREATE TABLE project
    (prj_code int , prj_name varchar(255) );


CREATE TABLE task
    (id int , prj_code int, task_name varchar(255) );

INSERT INTO project VALUES (1,'myproj1');    
INSERT INTO project VALUES (2,'myproj2');

INSERT INTO task VALUES (1,1,'testing');
INSERT INTO task VALUES (2,1,'prod');
INSERT INTO task VALUES (3,1,'prod2');
INSERT INTO task VALUES (4,1,'testing2');

INSERT INTO task VALUES (5,2,'mytask1');
INSERT INTO task VALUES (6,2,'mytask2');
```

[Please see the fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3c53e/2/0)

**EDIT:**

Want to pivot table to retrieve the 3 smallests tasks Ids in columns for each project

Comment: What is the question?  What have you tried?

Comment: the result set should be one row per project record.

Comment: I need 3 latest records from table - task, for every mataching record from  project table.

Comment: Still no question, that I can see.

Comment: Decently sure he's asking how to pivot out the data from his Task table...@user1130456 - give us what you would want the results from your script to be using your demo inserts here

Comment: The Id of all task are really the same? Your table have the same ID and don´t have time to know what records are the last. If the Ids are differents, it is easy to solve your question. You need the 3 last (biggest ones) Ids, is it??

Comment: @Twelfth kind of yes. But only 3 first 3 records please see the fiddle result set(hard coded the task records)

Comment: The concept of first and last is not defined here. First and last based on what factor?

Comment: Sorry @Nizam , task id is unique and sequential. updated the fiddle  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/796cf/1/0  , I can't update the original post

Comment: @Nizam I need 3 smallest id's of the task table per project record. And result should show only one record per project table.

Comment: Can anybody please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a hideous solution, but I think it illustrates a way to accomplish this.  I don't assume any pivoting capabilies, not knowing what version of Oracle you're running.

```
with tasks as (
  select
    a.prj_code, a.prj_name,
    b.id, b.task_name,
    row_number() over (partition by a.prj_code order by b.id) as rn
  from
    project a
    join task b on
      a.prj_code = b.prj_code
), pivotdata as (
  select
    prj_code, prj_name,
    case when rn = 1 then task_name end as task_1,
    case when rn = 2 then task_name end as task_2,
    case when rn = 3 then task_name end as task_3
  from tasks
)
select
  prj_code, prj_name,
  max (task_1) as task_1, max (task_2) as task_2,
  max (task_3) as task_3
from pivotdata
group by
  prj_code, prj_name
```

Output:

```
Prj Code   Prj Name    Task 1   Task 2  Task 3
1          myproj1     testing  prod    prod2
2          myproj2     mytask1  mytask2
```

Answer (score 4):

This code does the trick. You need to use `RANK` to select the 3 smallests IDs and then pivot table:

```
WITH tasks AS (
select 
   A.prj_code,
   prj_name,
   RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY A.PRJ_CODE ORDER BY ID ) RANK, 
   ID, 
   TASK_NAME
from task A
inner join project B
   on A.PRJ_CODE = B.PRJ_CODE
order by A.prj_code)


select PRJ_CODE, prj_name, sum(T1) T1, sum(T2) T2, sum(T3) T3
from tasks A
PIVOT (max(ID) for RANK IN ('1' as T1 ,'2' as T2 ,'3' as T3 )) B
GROUP BY PRJ_CODE, prj_name
```

OR

use the code bellow to have the tasks names

```
select PRJ_CODE, prj_name, max(T1) T1, max(T2) T2, max(T3) T3
from tasks A
PIVOT (max(TASK_NAME) for RANK IN ('1' as T1 ,'2' as T2 ,'3' as T3 )) B
GROUP BY PRJ_CODE, prj_name
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/796cf/43/0)

Comment: Nice practical demo of the pivot function.